# RUBY: Rotate Function not Working on Array in Unit Test

Tags: arrays, ruby, function, sorting

I am testing code output in Ruby. I want to use Ruby's `rotate()` function to make the last element of an array the first element, the original first element becomes the second element in the array, etc.

**CODE**

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
class TestMagicBus < MiniTest::Test

  def setup
    @bus = MagicBus.new(["Peter","James","Bardoe","Patrick","Jake","Samson","Dave"])
  end

  def test_move_the_last_passenger_to_the_front_of_the_bus
    assert_equal "Peter", @bus[0]
    @bus.rotate(-1)
    print(@bus)
    assert_equal "Dave", @bus[0]
  end
```

**TEST RESULT**

```
["Peter", "James", "Bardoe", "Patrick", "Jake", "Samson", "Dave"]F

Failure:
TestMagicBus#test_move_the_last_passenger_to_the_front_of_the_bus [magic_bus.rb:56]:
Expected: "Dave"
  Actual: "Peter"


rails test magic_bus.rb:52
```

Why is `rotate()` not doing anything?

DEFINITION of CLASS MAGICBUS

```
class MagicBus < Array

  attr_writer :seating

end
```

Comment: You might use rotate! instead.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `class MagicBus`?

Comment: @iBug Done... note that `@bus = @bus.rotate(-1)` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Ruby built-in methods that does not end with `!` creates a copy of the operating object, so `@bus.rotate` create a new MagicBus object with the rotated result, and that's why `@bus = @bus.rotate -1` works.

To modify objects in-place, there's an [`Array#rotate!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate-21) method:

```
@bus.rotate! -1
```

Comment: "Most Ruby built-in methods that does not end with `!` creates a copy of the operating object" – That is not really true. Many `Array` methods mutate the receiver and they don't have a bang, e.g. `replace`, `clear`, `delete_if`, `keep_if`, `<<`, `[]=`, `append`, `push`, `concat`, `delete`, `delete_at`, `fill`, `insert`, `pop`, `prepend`, `unshift`, `shift`. The bang simply marks the "more surprising" of a pair of methods. It has nothing to so with mutation (see `Process::exit!` for example) and it will only exist when there are two methods that do the same thing, but one is more surprising.